# Has anyone had this problem and solved it or found a solution[Openshift]?

Tags: openshift

I get this issue with Openshift everytime. It is failing to pull an image or something. It started between 4:10pm and 7:00pm today. I want any information at all; what the image is, a solution or even if I can't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now quay.io is experiencing outage, look here: https://status.quay.io/ .
And it may need to take more time to recover that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. That kinda sucks for my uni assignment, though. I even spent the last 2 hours searching for ways to fix it.